# Fixing issue with REGEXMATCH formula where it highlights entire row instead of row that actually meets the criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I used the formula in Conditional Formatting:

```
=REGEXMATCH(A2, TEXTJOIN("|", 1,    FILTER(INDIRECT("Semi-Blacklist!A:A"),  INDIRECT("Semi-Blacklist!A:A")=FALSE)))
```

Issue is, instead of only highlighting the parts that match the condition, it highlights the entire row and wont stop. Is there any way or filter to add so it only filters out things that match the actual criteria?

[Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jwqosSrddjq49zCxBPUSGQE9SWGi2I2JSuiF_QF2l4U/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=REGEXMATCH(A2, TEXTJOIN("|", 1,    
 FILTER(INDIRECT("Semi-Blacklist!A:A"),  INDIRECT("Semi-Blacklist!A:A")=FALSE)))*(A2<>"")
```

and:

```
=REGEXMATCH(B2&"", TEXTJOIN("|", 1,    
 FILTER(INDIRECT("Semi-Blacklist!B:B"),  INDIRECT("Semi-Blacklist!D:D")=FALSE)))*(B2<>"")
```